# AWS Secret Manager password rotation not syncing with Kubernetes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have the following AWS Secret Manager:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secret" {
  name = "secret"
}
```

And rotation enabled here:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation" "secret-rotation" {
  secret_id           = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret.id
  rotation_lambda_arn = aws_lambda_function.primary.arn
  rotation_rules {
    automatically_after_days = 30
  }
}
```

This works totally fine on AWS and I am able to rotate the password. However, the Python code I have inside the `aws_lambda_function.primary.arn` which says to re-create a `kubernetes_job`:

```
import kubernetes as kubernetes
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()

configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
name = "job-1"
namespace = "default"

batch_v1 = client.BatchV1Api()

v1_job = batch_v1.read_namespaced_job(name, namespace)
v1_job.metadata.resource_version = None
v1_job.metadata.uid = None
v1_job.spec.selector = None
v1_job.spec.template.metadata.labels = None

v1_job.metadata.annotations = None
v1_job.metadata.managed_fields = None

batch_v1.delete_namespaced_job(name, namespace)

batch_v1.create_namespaced_job(namespace, v1_job)
```

This pulls in the OLD AWS Secret password, not the newly rotated password. Is there a field I have to set to `None` to get it to refresh the password?

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the lambda code? It is difficult to understand how this fits into the rest of the lambda function handler. Also, you should be able to pull the secret from the boto3 client. This is roughly what the code will look like `service_client = boto3.client('secretsmanager', endpoint_url=os.environ['SECRETS_MANAGER_ENDPOINT']); secret = service_client.get_secret_value(SecretId=arn, VersionStage="AWSCURRENT")`